# Wired router only works with one computer

Tags: router

Both my desktop computers connect to this router. I checked with ISP and modem was fine. I plugged directly to one of the computer, it works.

The router is brand new.
Starting a few days ago the connection would be unstable.
I replaced the ethernet cables with brand new ones. nothing changed.
I tried resetting the router and the modem. nothing.

The internet only seems to work when only one of the desktop ethernet is connected to this router. When I plug in the second desktops ethernet cable, the internet works for about 20 seconds or so until the internet doesn't work on both desktop.

If I remove one of the ethernet cable, the internet begins working again.
I am out of ideas as to what could be going on. I updated the firmware.

Comment: What are the IP addresses of the two computers? Are they the same by any chance?

Comment: Are both of the computers configured to use DHCP (sometimes called "obtain ip address automatically", etc.) or are they configured with fixed IP addresses? Check in the internet settings for the computers.

Comment: @DavidPostill Yes. They have the same IP address when I go to a website.

Comment: @JAsonC yes when I go to view network connections and click on properties, it says obtain ip address and dns automatically.

Comment: @user299709 1) DavidPostill was referring to their LAN IPs, not the internet IPs; that is the local IPs that your router gives them, which is different from the IP address visible from the outside world. 2) Do *both* machines have "obtain IP address and DNS automatically" selected?

Comment: Also, what operating system is on your desktops? Windows 7? Windows 8? OSX? Linux?

Comment: @JasonC win 7 both. Ipv4 Addy is different. Both have automatic IP and DNS. Dhcp enabled.

Comment: **With both computers plugged into the router** (and the internet therefore not working), can you do the following: In a command prompt (Start -> Run -> "cmd.exe") on both computers, type `ipconfig` and press enter. Copy + paste the output for your ethernet adapter for both computers into your post above. (Instructions for copying + pasting from the command prompt can be found [here](http://unlockforus.blogspot.com/2009/06/how-to-copy-paste-text-from-cmd-or.html)).

Comment: I am typing on my phone. No internet. Ipv4 192.168.0.3 and 192.168.0.2. Gateway is 192.168.0.1 for both.

Comment: My first guess would be a configuration problem on the router, but you say the router is brand new, and I have never seen a common router whose factory default LAN/DHCP settings didn't work out of the box. I can't think of anything besides a faulty router (it is suspicious that it worked, but then started causing problems a few days ago) or configuration problem; double check all the configuration settings on your router. ... continued

Comment: ...  It very well could be something simple but without being able to actually sit at your computer and poke around there's no way to tell for sure - therefore your best bet might just be to have a technician from your ISP come and look at it (just because they can physically examine your router and PCs, which we can't). Was the router given to you by your ISP or did you purchase it yourself? If you bought it yourself, what is the make and model? Did anything else change when this problem started happening a few days ago?

Comment: Also, one last question; is there anything else on your network besides your two PCs? For example, any wifi devices that you have set up, like laptops, phones, iPads, printers, etc.?

Comment: Yes. In fact I tried using another new router and result is same. Router settings have not hanged. No other devices on this router.

Answer (score 0):

Is the router also your connection to your ISP? In other words, do you also have a cable or DSL modem, etc. that the router connects to? If so, perhaps you are connecting the ISP connection (cable or DSL modem, etc) into the wrong port on the router. Most routers have one dedicated port for the connection to the ISP and multiple connections for the devices on the LAN (internal network.)

Back in the command prompt try the following commands on each computer while both are plugged in.

ping 192.168.0.1
ping 192.168.0.2
ping 192.168.0.3

Each command should result in 5 successful pings.